# SQLAlchemy INSERT IGNORE

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, insert

How can I insert multiple data records into table ignoring duplicates. I am using SQLAlchemy.

Thank you!

Answer (score 37, accepted):

`prefix_with("TEXT")` adds arbitrary text between `INSERT` and the rest of the SQL. `execute()` accepts a list of dictionaries with the records you would like to insert or a single dictionary if you only want to insert a single record.

The SQLite syntax for the behavior you're looking for:

```
inserter = table_object.insert().prefix_with("OR REPLACE")
inserter.execute([{'column1':'value1'}, {'column1':'value2'}])
```

Answer (score 3):

To always replace `INSERT` by `INSERT OR IGNORE`, you can use a [compiler extension](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/compiler.html#changing-the-default-compilation-of-existing-constructs):

```
from sqlalchemy.ext.compiler import compiles
from sqlalchemy.sql.expression import Insert

@compiles(Insert)
def _prefix_insert_with_ignore(insert, compiler, **kw):
    return compiler.visit_insert(insert.prefix_with('OR IGNORE'), **kw)
```

Or to do this only temporarily, call the `compiles` decorator manually and use `deregister` once you're done:

```
from sqlalchemy.ext.compiler import compiles, deregister
from sqlalchemy.sql.expression import Insert

def _prefix_insert_with_ignore(insert, compiler, **kw):
    return compiler.visit_insert(insert.prefix_with('OR IGNORE'), **kw)

compiles(Insert)(_prefix_insert_with_replace)
try:
    # do some inserts...
finally:
    deregister(Insert)
```

This does feel hacky because it's still a global change, but as long as you don't use threads and make sure everything is properly committed before the `deregister` call, it's probably okay.