# How can I insert multiple rows with INSERT REPLACE in peewee?

Tags: python, mysql, sql-insert, unique-constraint, peewee

I'm retrieving a json file from online that I want to insert into my database using peewee. The problem is that some of the rows may already exist in my database. The solution should be to either ignore or replace the duplicate rows.

The [`InsertQuery`](http://peewee.readthedocs.org/en/latest/peewee/api.html) function supports adding multiple rows, but I cannot figure out how to either suppress errors that the instance already exists or to replace the existing instance.

Starting with an empty database test, I run the following code

```
from peewee import *
from peewee import InsertQuery

database = MySQLDatabase('test', **{'password': 'researchServer', 'user': 'root'})

class BaseModel(Model):
    class Meta:
        database = database

class Image(BaseModel):
    url = CharField(unique=True)

database.connect()
database.create_tables([Image])
images= [{'url': 'one'}, {'url':'two'}]
try:
    image_entry = InsertQuery(Image, rows=images)
    image_entry.execute()
except:
    print 'error'
```

This produces no errors and successfully adds 'one' and 'two' to my table.

If I then run,

```
images= [{'url':'three'}, {'url': 'one'}, {'url':'four'}]
try:
    image_entry = InsertQuery(Image, rows=images)
    image_entry.execute()
except:
    print 'error'
```

The execute function throws an error and neither 'three' or 'four' get added to the database.

I suppose one solution would be to check each row before adding it to the database, but this seems like it would be more inefficient.

Comment: If it's not possible in peewee, I'd also like to know.

Comment: I've implemented this for SQLite (which uses INSERT OR REPLACE INTO), so adding just plain old "REPLACE" might be straightforward. Feel free to open a github ticket at https://github.com/coleifer/peewee/issues/new

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`on_conflict()`](http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/api.html#InsertQuery.on_conflict) or [`upsert()`](http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/api.html#InsertQuery.upsert) on your `InsertQuery`.

`on_conflict()` will add an SQL `ON CONFLICT` clause with the given argument but only works with SQLite. `upsert()` basically turns the query into a `REPLACE INTO` on MySQL. You still need to call `execute()` after.

Answer (score 0):

```
Image.insert_many(images).upsert(True).execute()
```

[peewee doc upsert](http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/api.html#InsertQuery.upsert)

Comment: This results in the following exception: AttributeError:
'ModelInsert' object has no attribute 'upsert'

Answer (score -1):

I haven't been able to find a solution in peewee, but here's one that I wrote for SQLAlchemy.

```
from sqlalchemy import Table, Column, Integer, String, MetaData, ForeignKey
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

#Make the table
metadata = MetaData()
image = Table('image', metadata,
              Column('url', String(250), primary_key=True))

db = create_engine('mysql://root:researchServer@localhost/test3')
metadata.create_all(db)

conn = engine.connect()

#Insert the first set of rows
images = [{'url': 'one'}, {'url': 'two'}]
inserter = db.image.insert()
conn.execute(inserter, images)

#Insert the second set of rows with some duplicates
images = [{'url': 'three'}, {'url': 'one'}, {'url':'four'}]
try:
    inserter = db.image.insert().prefix_with("IGNORE")
    conn.execute(inserter, images)
except:
    print 'error'
```

The key is using the 'prefix_with' method to add the 'ignore' to the SQL expression. I was greatly helped by [SQLAlchemy INSERT IGNORE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2218304/sqlalchemy-insert-ignore)