# SQLAlchemy look up and merge object before adding

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, sqlalchemy

I have an object which has foreign keys to another object. Let's call the first object `A` and the second object `B`. `A` can be represented as `(integer id, integer b_id, integer some_data)` and `B` can be represented as `(integer id, integer datum_one, integer datum_two)`

`datum_one` and `datum_two` form a unique composite in `B` (I think this is the right term - I don't want more than on entry in B with the same combination of these fields). However, I just want to reference the id in the ForeignKey pointing from `A` to `B`. It seems tedious and redundant to do something like a composite foreign key [like here](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/constraints.html).

I want to have functionality such that when I add `A` to my database, it first searches for a matching `B` which has the same `datum_one` and `datum_two`. If this exists, it uses the matching entry in the database, and otherwise it adds a new row to the table representing `B`.

Is there a way to accomplish this? I suspect the solution have have something to do with the merge directive, but I'm not sure how to get this functionality exactly.

One potential solution I considered was actually using the UNIQUE directive, but it seems like SQLAlchemy doesn't play nice with unique - I would basically need to just write my own error handling, which is an option but I was hoping SQLAlchemy would have a more elegant solution to this.

Comment: Merge cannot help you, as it operates on primary keys. When either selecting or inserting a new B based on datum values you don't have one. I don't quite understand how a composite foreign key would help you in this case either. What you have to do, and you've partly laid it out already, is use a unique constraint on the datums and based on that either insert or select existing (or the other way around, if you're mostly using existing datums). How exactly doesn't SQLAlchemy "play nice" with unique constraints?

Comment: Since you've tagged this as [tag:sqlite], you could first `INSERT OR IGNORE` into B and then select id from B. It'll ignore the unique constraint violation if any and then select the (possibly inserted) id.

Comment: See for example [this question and answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2218304/sqlalchemy-insert-ignore) about how to use DB specific features like `OR IGNORE` in SQLAlchemy. Also see [this answer by Michael Bayer](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/sqlalchemy/3UjRwQ0M8kk) about `Session.merge`, primary keys and unique constraints.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should just handle this yourself before inserting your object to the database. From the docs... http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/events.html

```
from sqlalchemy import event

# standard decorator style
@event.listens_for(SomeSchemaClassOrObject, 'before_create')
def receive_before_create(target, connection, **kw):
    "listen for the 'before_create' event"

    # ... (event handling logic) ...
```

Comment: Ah, I like this solution. I had already written some code to handle this but this particular approach may be cleaner.